# Codeigniter run code in background

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing an iOS app and I need to call to a web developed with CodeIgniter. The problem is that I have the response very quickly, but then I need to do some actions with it in CodeIgniter.

How can I do it in background?

My code is something like this:

```
$data = json_decode($response);
echo $response;

//Data has around 100 rows
foreach ($data as $info)
{
     //Database inserts and updates 
}
```

If I comment the foreach, it works perfect, but with it, it takes a lot of time.

I don't want to speed up database, because that's not the problem... what really takes time its what i need to do with my data...

Comment: It seems you have a performance issue in database inserts and updates, could you post this part of the code? than we can better help you

Comment: We'll need to have an idea of the database tables involved, roughly how many rows each has, and what indexes and constraints each has. You _can_ background this process, but it may not be necessary.

Comment: I don't want to speed up database, because that's not the problem... what really takes time its what i need to do with my data before inserts and updates

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue in two ways.

1. Create a cronjob to do the time consuming task in the main method you just need to add an enrty to a job table to the post processing after sending the response. So reponse will not wait until all the processing is completed. Also you can schedule the cronjob time as you need depend on the urgency of the post processing and server load.
2. You can use CodeIgniter hook function to do the processing after sending the response to the caller. The hook method will be "post_system" Read more about it at https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: I don't know how can I do it.
If I use hooks, it runs every controller..
I've never done a cronjob, what is it?

Comment: It is nothing but scheduling controller method using your web server. In your web control panel you can see the cronjob feature or need to use operating systems scheduler feature in web server to call ur controler method URL. So can transfer the heavy work to this background processing.

Comment: But, if i'm not wrong, I can't call a cron job from my controller, I have to do it from command line (if i do that, I'll not have my $data. 
What I really need is to send the response and then execute some extra code with the data that I have. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes I understood. What I am saying is to divide the post processing in to a cronjob. In the main processing before sending the response you can add an entry to a queue table to indicate which $data to be processed and in queue just read the entry and process.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like below,

```
class Proc_test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Proc_text::Index is called at ".$this->rightnow()."<br>";
        $param = 5000000;
        $command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools proc1 $param > /dev/null &";
        exec($command);
        $command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools proc2 $param > /dev/null &";
        echo "Proc_text::Index is done at ".$this->rightnow()."<br>";
    }

    //a helper to give time of day with microseconds
    public function rightnow()
    {
        $time = microtime(true);
        $micro_time = sprintf("%06d", ($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);
        $date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro_time, $time));
        return $date->format("H:i:s.u");
    }
}
```

Here background command executes as per below example.

```
$command = "php ".FCPATH."index.php tools proc1 $param > /dev/null &";
```

It's basically a cli command which follows this form
 "php absolute/path/to/codeigniter/index.php controller method argument_1 argument_2 argument_n > pipe to null statement".

Ref. Url : https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-67870.html