# Running a function in the background in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, telegram-bot, background-process

I am trying to send a message to all my **telegram bot subscribers**. However, due to their large number `curl_exec` inside `a loop of thousands users` take lots of time to finish the function.

This is a problem, because if users send some request from my bot during the loop, they **have to wait** untill telegram api answers to my **previous loop requests** and then only to their requests. There will be confusion to TELEGRAM API also, and it **may repeat same message** to the users **2-3 times** at this stage.

So I want to do it in the **background**, so that users **keep working with the bot and not wait**, and also I will not care how long it will take to send message to all subscribers.

I would be very grateful if you could help.

Comment: how about a cron job?

Comment: @ADyson Have never used them before. Do they solve the problem?

Comment: Well yes in the sense that the job runs in a separate process with no dependency on your webserver or user interface, and you can trigger it automatically to run at scheduled intervals - so if your application puts a request into a queue (which can just be a database table, potentially) showing what message(s) needs to be sent, then next time the cron job runs the script would get the next item from the queue and send all the messages associated with that job item.

Comment: @ADyson Is this possible with cron job -> every second send 20 curl requests (to 20 users) to an API and next time start with the 21st, 42nd, 63th, etc....? In one minute send 1200 requests each second knowing from which offset to start?

Comment: Yes, as long as the script saves the offset it finished at, so it can check that the next time it runs and start from there. Although the smallest time interval you can specify with cron is 1 minute - so perhaps you could set it to process a higher number within one minute instead (I doubt you'd get through 20 curl requests in 1 second in any case). Or of course in theory there's nothing to stop you writing your own service which can try to process data more frequently.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, good person for your help. I think it's not what I need. I know there is a way to process in the background but how to do it in CodeIgniter, no clue!?!

Comment: Why isn't it what you need, exactly? What requirement is not fulfilled by the suggestion? Anyway CodeIgniter is a web framework, its purpose is to make an application to respond to HTTP requests. It does not directly have any background processing capabilities. That's why I say that you need a separate background service of some sort. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382011/codeigniter-run-code-in-background

Answer (score 0):

check this out

```
 function broadcast($message) {
        $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . getenv('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN') . '/sendMessage';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'chat_id=' . getenv('TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID') . '&text=' . $message);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: What makes it run in the background? It's just a simple sending Message function. Also, to only one user not even a loop of users.